# Interstellar KSP - Not getting science from IR Satellite

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have put the IR Satellite into orbit on my unmanned ship. But for some reason I'm not getting science.

- I have Helium Cryostats (3 with the dish connected directly on to them).
- I have power being supplied (although the item doesn't directly say that it needs it).
- I have activated the Deep scanner.

What am I doing wrong?

Theory:

Is it possible that the IR Telescope will only work while the player is 'in' the ship?

Comment: This mist be new to Interstellar, I haven't seen such a part before.

Comment: I remember Scott Manley mentioning some issues with some of the config files for Interstellar parts that provide science.  Perhaps, that's what's happening here.